# in selenium the get command doesn't navigate to given URL and displays that it's missing a 'self' argument

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm with Python 3.5 and Selenium to write a program which pulls up google.com in Chrome. However, the get command says is takes two arguments: self and url. What is a self variable? Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

#using .Chrome() gives me an error, but .Chrome doesn't
driver= webdriver.Chrome

#PyCharm says it should be driver.get(self,url) 
driver.get("google.com")
```

thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Does it work if you add the http? `driver.get("http://www.google.com")`

Comment: You should use `.Chrome()`. What is the error with `Chrome()`

Answer (score 1):

The following works

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

Please provide the error if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: The issue was that I needed to add the chromedriver to my PATH. Thanks for the help!